# Sql - Query to get total number of records in table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have table like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bltV9.png)

I need to get the data only whose **age** > 10, along with that i need to get the total number of records present in the table. ie. in this example it is **4 records**. what i need is in single query i need to get the total number of records present in table and columns which i query.

Query will be somewhat like

```
SELECT ID, NAME, count(TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IN TABLE) as Count from MYTABLE WHERE AGE > 10
```

Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, c.cnt as Count 
FROM MYTABLE CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM MYTABLE) c
WHERE AGE > 10 ;
```

Both databases support window functions, but they are not really helpful here, because the count is not filtered in the same way as the outer query.  If you do want the filter for both, then in the most recent versions you can do:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE AGE > 10 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using scalar subquery

```
SELECT ID, NAME, age,(select count(*) from mytable WHERE AGE > 10) as Count 
from MYTABLE 
WHERE AGE > 10
```